# How to determine number of threads used cores in ARM processors.

Tags: multithreading, arm, cpu-usage, hardware

I'm trying to us evaluate some aspects of the CPU/GPU performance in ARM processors. I never coded directly into hardware.

That's why I'm asking if there is a possible way to determine the number of cores/Shader cores that are used by a program runuing on an ARM processors. And how many threads per core.

May use C++ and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer depends upon what environment you are executing in. If you are executing your program on top of an OS, it should have calls that you can make that return various architectural information. Look at the OS system call reference manual. For example, look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.vxworks/A2AcUf3xwHY) for vxworks.

If you are executing on bare metal (unlikely since you included Java), there are some registers that you can query to get such architectural information. Check out the architecture's instruction set manual. Here's a thread that looks at [determining CPU usage on bare metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641294/cpu-usage-measurment-on-arm-bare-metal-system).